# How do I style exported and slotted parts in svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

Does Svelte `slot`s function like vanilla-js/dom in any way (I can't seem to get it to work).

In html/js I can do:

```html
<style>
    body {color: red;}
    /* style exposed part from outside */
    my-element::part(header) {color: green;}
</style>

<h1>Hello World</h1>   

<my-element>
    <div slot="header"><strong>Header</strong></div>
    <div slot="body">Body</div>
</my-element>

<script>
    customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
                <style>
                    .container { 
                        border: solid 1px blue;
                        padding: 5px;
                        position: relative;

                        &:after {
                            content: "my-element";
                            display: block;
                            position: absolute;
                            bottom: -.5em;
                            right: 5px;
                            border: inherit;
                            background-color: white;
                            padding: inherit;
                        }
                    }
                    /* style inserted/slotted part from inside */
                    [part="body"] ::slotted(div) { background-color: lightyellow; }
                </style>
                <div class="container">
                    <header part="header"><slot name="header"></slot></header>
                    <hr>
                    <div part="body"><slot name="body"></slot></div>
                </div>
            `;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Where the `h1` will be red from the global style, the element marked with `part="header"` is styled from the outside to be green, and the content slotted into `slot="body"` is styled from the inside (of the shadow dom) to have a lightyellow background.

I can't figure out how to do any of this (controlled) cross-boundary styling in svelte? (e.g. when using `AppShell::part(content)` I get an error:

```
[plugin:vite-plugin-svelte] C:/srv/svelte/yoda5/src/routes/+layout.svelte:23:18 Expected a valid CSS identifier

C:/srv/svelte/yoda5/src/routes/+layout.svelte:23:18

21 |  
22 |  <style>
23 |      AppShell::part(content) {
   |                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lesson on [slots here](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/slots).  It is always best to refer to the tool's documentation.  Svelte's learn website is excellent.

```html
// Slotted component, say Test.svelte.
<div class="private-parent">
    <slot />
</div>

<style>
    div.private-parent {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Then, you consume the component:

```html
<script>
    import Test from './Test.svelte';
</script>

<Test>
    <!-- This is the slot's content -->
    <p class="outside-style">Hello!</p>
</Test>

<style>
    p.outside-style {
        color: darkred;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Asking here since I've not found an answer in the svelte docs. Not sure what your example is supposed to demonstrate..? `part="..."` and `::part(...)` lets the component author specify that the end-user can control styling on an otherwise hidden part of the (shadow) dom. The `<header part="header"><slot name="header"></slot></header>` in the shadow dom in my example lets the end-user style the header tag in the shadow dom with `my-element::part(header) {...}`.  In your example, how would you make the private-parent non-private, ie. stylable by the consumer of the component?

Answer (score 0):

In Svelte, you can achieve a similar effect using context and props to pass styling information between components. However, Svelte doesn't use the ::part() syntax like Web Components. Instead, you can create props in your Svelte components and pass styles as needed.

Here's an example using Svelte:

```
<!-- AppShell.svelte -->
<script>
  export let contentStyle = {};
</script>

<style>
  /* Your global styles here */
  body {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div class="app-shell" style={contentStyle}>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

```
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import AppShell from './AppShell.svelte';
</script>

<AppShell contentStyle="color: green;">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</AppShell>
```

In Svelte, you can achieve a similar effect using context and props to pass styling information between components. However, Svelte doesn't use the `::part()` syntax like Web Components. Instead, you can create props in your Svelte components and pass styles as needed.

Here's an example using Svelte:

```html
<!-- AppShell.svelte -->
<script>
  export let contentStyle = {};
</script>

<style>
  /* Your global styles here */
  body {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div class="app-shell" style={contentStyle}>
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import AppShell from './AppShell.svelte';
</script>

<AppShell contentStyle="color: green;">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</AppShell>
```

In this example, the `App` component includes an `AppShell` component as a wrapper. The `AppShell` component takes a prop called `contentStyle`, which is a string containing CSS styles. These styles are then applied to the content of the `AppShell` component.

Remember that the use of inline styles should be minimized, and using a CSS class or a more structured styling approach is generally preferable. In more complex scenarios, you might want to consider using a state management library like Redux or the context API for passing styles and state between components.

Svelte encourages a more component-centric approach to styling, and while it might not have the same `::part()` syntax as Web Components, you can achieve a similar separation of concerns by designing your components in a way that promotes encapsulation and reusability.